# finding specific instances of substring in string in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a string that's of the format:

"((Random filler goes here))"

How do I get the random filler that's within the two parentheses?

Comment: Your example underspecifies the problem.  Are you just trying to remove the outer two characters on each side, or could there be words that aren't part of the filler?  Could there be more than one bit of filler you need, e.g. `((filler1)) ((filler2))`?  Could you have filler doubly-nested, e.g. `((some filler ((inside)) ))`?  If so, what would you want to return?  Etc.

Comment: I'm trying to extract the part, excluding the (( )) which are nested in a larger string. The slice notation works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it always starts and ends with the parameters, the easiest way is slicing:

```
s= "((Random filler goes here))"
print s[2:-2]
```

If it isn't, Cyber's answer would be the most appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `regex` solution

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "((Random filler goes here))"
>>> re.search('\(\((.*?)\)\)',s).group(1)
'Random filler goes here'
```

Answer (score 0):

Through `re.split` function,

```
>>> import re
>>> s= "((Random filler goes here))"
>>> re.split(r'(?:\)\)|\(\()', s)[1]
'Random filler goes here'
```

Answer (score 0):

An overcomplicated (and unreadable) solution, but I do like itertools.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, filterfalse, dropwhile
>>> s = "sdodsf((NEEDED TEXT))dsfoh"
>>> ''.join(takewhile(lambda c: ')' != c, filterfalse('('.__eq__, (dropwhile(lambda c: c != '(', s)))))
'NEEDED TEXT'
```